# Pass copy of object to method

Tags: scala

I've run into an issue where, when using a loop and passing an object into a method, my object is being modified when the method returns, breaking the next iteration.

The code I'm using is quite elaborate, so I'll simplify with the following:

```
val car: Car = expensiveMethod("greenCar")

for (i <- 1 to 5) {
    foo(car)
}

def foo (car: Car) = {
    assert(car.name == "greenCar")
    car.name = "redCar"
}
```

`expensiveMethod` is, as it sounds, expensive, so I'd prefer not to call it inside the for loop every time. 
Car is also not a case class, so I can't use the built in `copy` method.

Is there a simple way to send a copy of `car` into `foo`, or an alternate approach?

Comment: Car car is Java not scala and your foo method is not a valid Scala method (it doesn't compile) since you're doing a reassignment to a val...

Comment: Oops. Fixed the method signature, should be fine now.

Comment: No, there still is a reassignment to a val (car.name = although car is a val as an argument of a method).

Comment: @Simon There's no reassignment to val. car isn't being reassigned. I'm modifying a var member variable of a val object, which is allowed.

Comment: You should have showed you're Car class definition in this case, I assumed it was a Case Class as it generally is in Scala. Edit: my bad, it is said... ;)

Comment: To be fair I did explicitly state it's not a case class.

Comment: Can you paste your `Car` class?

Comment: +1 for `chengpohi`'s question on `Car`'s definition. Also, it'd be helpful to know the method signature for what logic you're implementing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that **name** member of your **Car** class is public and mutable.
Also from definition of foo function the signature is foo: (car: Car)Unit, which could mean that it is not a pure function, a side effecting function (or procedure) in this case as its modifying the parameter. You should explicitly create a copy of parameter and mutate the copy.